# Django - Url patatterns dose not work

Tags: python, django, url

I started working with Django yesterday and I have a little error. I searched on the internet but I cant find the answer for my problem. I made the main app and then I make a little app and tried to link it to the main. Here is my code

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

ulrpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('^$', include('personal.urls'));
]
```

**in my personal.urls I have**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

ulrpatterns = [
  path('^$', views.index, name="index");
]
```

**and in views.index I have**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')
```

Any help would be awesome, thank you!!!

Comment: Try `r'^/$'` instead.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I changed in both urls.py files and still same error

Comment: Use `path_re`, `path` does *not* work with regexes.

Comment: Or better, use `path('', ..)`. OP's version wouldn't work even with `re_path`, because it terminates the including regex.

Comment: Yea, it work with path('', ...), thank you @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool here: since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), there are basically two ways to specify a URL:

1. with a regex through [**`re_path`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re_path), [**`url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#url) is an "alias" of this, but will probably eventually get deprecated; and
2. by using a specific "path pattern" syntax with [**`path`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path)

Here you somehow *mixed* the two, and use `path(..)` function for a "regex-specified" URL.

## Using `path` for *path pattern*-based URLs

We can also fix it by using `path`:

```
#  urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

ulrpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('', include('personal.urls'));
]
```

and:

```
#  personal/urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

ulrpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name="index");
]
```

## Using `re_path` for *regular expression*-based URLs

We can also fix it by using `re_path` instead:

```
#  urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path, include

ulrpatterns = [
  re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  re_path('^$', include('personal.urls'));
]
```

and:

```
#  personal/urls.py

from django.urls import re_path, include
from . import views

ulrpatterns = [
  re_path('^$', views.index, name="index");
]
```

Comment: but I tried second method and it said  "Can not import name path_re" How can I solve that?

Comment: @Horatiu123456: yes it is `re_path`, not `path_re` :)